# URL behavior to access server side resource in Java/J2EE

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets, web-applications

My deployment descriptor is as follows

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>postServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.http.post.PostServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>postServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/postServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>postServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.http.post.PostServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>postServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern/>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I'm Able to access PostServlet by hitting following URLs

Pls assume /url/to/my/server as

```
http://myserver:8080

/url/to/my/server/MyWebAppName
/url/to/my/server/MyWebAppName  (few white spaces at the end of context)
/url/to/my/server/HTTPMethods/
/url/to/my/server/HTTPMethods/////
/url/to/my/server/HTTPMethods///postServlet
/url/to/my/server/HTTPMethods///postServlet   (few white spaces here too)
```

Can some one pls explain this behavior by generalizing things?

How ever, if any space is present in between, it failes
    /url/to/my/server/HTTPMethods/// //
This makes sense, because browser encodes spaces with %20

Is there any specific reason why trailing spaces are ignored

And failure in case of below URL
    /url/to/my/server/HTTPMethods/////postServlet//

Answer (score 0):

It might be quite confusing to read, but all your questions can be answered by the [URL spec](http://url.spec.whatwg.org/)

Basically, leading and trailing whitespaces are simply stripped off (if you really need white spaces as part of the URL you should encode them as %20

Regarding the notation HTTPMethods///postServlet, multiple slashes are simply treated as a single one.